# start to load on click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want some content to start loading when i click on a link. i dont want it to use any bandwidth before i click on that link. also how to implement that rotating cursor animation that is seen in almost all lightboxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the $.ajax() function to load content dynamically.

For the animation, find an animated .gif (http://www.ajaxload.info can generate one for you). What I usually do is:

```
$(element).html('<img src="loading.gif">');
```

Then run your ajax function, and on success replace the loading gif with the loaded content.